# En dbForge Studio 2019, ¿Como hago para mostrar dentro del "Data" (resultado de query) dos select en una vista comparativa?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, forge

Si tengo 2 select simples, como hago para verlos al mismo tiempo en una vista comparativa, sin tener que correrme de pestaña.
Actualmente mi Db Forge me lo muestra en pestañas separadas, sobre las cuales tengo que ir moviéndome y no ayuda en la comparativa (obviamente si tengo muchos mas select, peor).
Sql Server si muestra varios select uno abajo del otro, pudiendo comparar diferentes consultas.

En resumen, necesito en dbForge Studio 2019, simular este comportamiento que tiene SQL SERVER:
[image: captura del uso de select comparativos en SQL Sever]

Mientras que dbForge lo muestra en pestañas o tab:
[image: captura de la forma en que muestra dbForge 2 select]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenas. Se entiende con la imagen lo que necesito, sino subo una captura de como lo veo en dbForge. Gracias!